# What's the difference between "will swim" and "going to swim"?

Tags: tense

> We will swim next Monday.
> We are going to swim next Monday.
> We will go swimming next Monday.

Which one is correct?

What's the difference between "will swim" and "going to swim"?

Comment: Why do you think one of them is "correct", and the others presumably "not correct"?

Comment: Your third example raises completely different syntactic issues. The first two could be addressed with a different verb, as 1: *I will speak soon* vs 2:  *I am going to speak soon*, but the construction *I will go speaking soon* doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

All three are correct, but not all natural sounding.  "Will swim" and "going to swim" sound like formal solutions, you might see it in an example like this:

"How will we get to the island?  We will swim next Monday."
and
"When will our Navy training start?  We are going to swim next Monday."

But you are talking about the fun activity, which is usually described as "swimming."  So the most common future tense usage would be:

"What do we have planned for vacation? We will go swimming next Monday."

or funny sounding but even more common:

"We're going swimming next Monday."

Or in a common present tense usage:

"Let's go for a swim."